# Add Objects between <li> in <ol> in an Angular Project

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend

I have this in a component.html of my angular project

```
  <li *ngFor="let activity of dto.activities | sortHistoryActivity; trackBy: trackByFn">
    <span>
      <a (click)="scrollToHistoryActivity(activity.firstTaskId, activity.firstActivityId)">{{activity.title}}</a>
    </span>
    <p class="timestamp">{{activity.startTime | date:"dd.MM.yyyy, HH:mm:ss"}}</p>
  </li>
</ol>
```

I want to add objects between a certain amount of li's, which doesnt reset the  to 1. again, but keeps the number running for every object added. The Object I want to add, shouldn't have a number.

Don't be all too harsh, since this is my first question.

image of example

[image: image of example]

So I will try to go more in detail: In this app, for every action, there will be added the name of the action with the number of the action. (in order of when performed) 
Now I want to add some HTML between one of the list elements, without resetting the number of the  
(As shown in the image)

Comment: I have a hard time understanding your question. Could you try to rephrase it? Maybe give an example?

Comment: @sloth I have updated the question, hopefully you can understand it better now :)

Comment: @Cryptorian420 I think you would be better off creating a live demo in stackblitz. A bit of HTML and an image could be interpreted in 100 different ways.

Comment: @Cryptorian420 So object will have the number? activity??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the following HTML:

```
<ol #orderedListRef>
  <li>first</li>
  <li>second</li>
  <li>third</li>
  <li>fourth</li>
  <li>fifth</li>
  <li>sixth</li>
</ol>
```

The following Typescript Code will take the fourth list item as an example and places something behind it:

```
@ViewChild('orderedListRef') olRef: ElementRef<HTMLOListElement>

.
.
.

// get the native element via the ViewChild
const ol: HTMLOListElement = olRef.nativeElement;

// get the fourth list item that is a direct child of the ordered list
const fourthElement = ol.querySelector("li:nth-child(4)");

// create something you want to put after the list item
const divToAppend: HTMLDivElement = document.createElement("div");
// fill it with some HTML or text
divToAppend.innerHTML = "<h1>example text</h1>";

// place the element after your listItem
fourthElement.after(divToAppend);
```

This example results in:

```
<ol #orderedListRef>
  <li>first</li>
  <li>second</li>
  <li>third</li>
  <li>fourth</li>
  <h1>example text</h1> <-----
  <li>fifth</li>
  <li>sixth</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is conditionally add elements, You can achieve that by using the ng-container component provided by the angular as follows:

```
<ol>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let activity of dto.activities | sortHistoryActivity; trackBy: trackByFn">
    <!-- if activity doesn't contain number -->
        <p *ngIf="!activity.number">Insert of html</p>

     <!-- if activity contains number -->
        <li *ngIf="activity.number">
            <span>
              <a (click)="scrollToHistoryActivity(activity.firstTaskId, activity.firstActivityId)">{{activity.title}}</a>
            </span>
            <p class="timestamp">{{activity.startTime | date:"dd.MM.yyyy, HH:mm:ss"}}</p>
        </li>
    </ng-container>
</ol>
```

Comment: This helps, but is not exactly what im looking for. What I want, is after the first 3 activities, to be added some html that isn't inside the <ol> but still looks as if it's inside it. I want to add subtitles in a way, which don't have a number on the left. I know how to do this in standard html, but not with angular. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

If the number is important, I would recommend storing this in the model and taking control over what is displayed.

To answer your question directly, you can state the start number of an `ol` using the `start` attribute.

```html
<p>Example</p>
<ol>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
</ol>

<p>Insert of html</p>
<ol start="4">
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
</ol>
```

This still requires you to track some state, so I still think it would be preferable to store the order in your model and bind your HTML to the order number in the model.

```js
dto: {
  activities: {
    order: 1,
    name: 'Text'
  },
  // ... etc
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let activity of dto.activities">
    {{activity.order}}. {{activity.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
```